# React has no exported member 'Props'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-router, typescript-typings

I've searched all over for a solution to this issue, and haven't had any luck.  I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ~/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/applyRouterMiddleware.d.ts
(4,43): error TS2305: Module ‘”~/node_modules/react/react".export=' has no exported member 'Props'.
```

There are hundreds of these, related to most all the @types definition files referencing properties not exported.

I'm using webpack for the build process here.  Here is the **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: { historyApiFallback: true },
  context: root(),
  entry: './src/index.tsx',

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.scss', '.css' ],
    root: root('src'),
    alias: {
      //inject environment variables via aliases
      conf: isProd() ? './conf/production.js' : './conf/development.js',
    },
  },

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js', //the output js file
    path: root('dist'), //build directory
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },

  externals: {
    fs: 'fs',
    winston: 'winston',
    system: '{}',
    file: '{}',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s)?css$/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract('css-loader!postcss-loader'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader', //reference by npm module or path to loader file
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.eot$|\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
        exclude: root('node_modules'),
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    new StaticHTMLPlugin(
      'bundle.js',
      root('src/Routing.tsx'),
      [ '.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.css', '.scss' ]
    ),
  ],
}
```

Here is a copy of the **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/history": "^2.0.39",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
  "@types/react": "^0.14.44",
  "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.18",
  "@types/react-router": "^2.0.38",
  "@types/winston": "0.0.29",
  "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
  "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
  "fs": "0.0.1-security",
  "history": "^4.3.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "postcss-assets": "^4.1.0",
  "postcss-assets-rebase": "^0.4.0",
  "postcss-cssnext": "^2.8.0",
  "postcss-inline-svg": "^2.1.2",
  "postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
  "precss": "^1.4.0",
  "react": "^15.3.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
  "react-router": "^3.0.0",
  "stylelint": "^7.4.0",
  "ts-loader": "^0.9",
  "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
  "tslint": "^3.15",
  "tslint-config-standard": "^1.3.0",
  "tslint-eslint-rules": "^1.5.0",
  "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
  "tslint-react": "^1.0.0",
  "typescript": "^2.0.3",
  "typescript-react-router-static-html-webpack-plugin": "^0.1",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
  "winston": "^2.2.0"
}
```

Any ideas on what could be going on here?  I'm not very familiar with the React lib itself.  I don't see the properties being exported directly, but I haven't dug into the lib very deep to see if they're being exported in another fashion.

It seems strange to me that I'd be the only one experiencing this issue if it's an inconsistency between the React lib and the @types/react typings.  This is why I'm leaning towards this being some sort of config issue.

I've run the project on `tsc` as well and it seems to actually build things properly.  It's hard to know for certain though b/c tsc outputs thousands of garbage lines in the console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution here was to set the `tsconfig.json` prop, `allowJs` to `false`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": false
}
```

Now, the question I have here is why?  Can anyone explain?